# Importing csv with python by timestemp range

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have about 100 csv files (at this moment, tomorrow will be more) in one location,  updating every day with 24-40 new files. So, what is the best way to import files just from the past day, but the other way than this where I need to put file name:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/data/testingfile-PM_18707-2017_06_14-05_03_23__382.csv', delimiter = ';', low_memory=False)
data1 = pd.read_csv('/data/testingfile--PM_18707-2017_06_14-06_30_56__131.csv', delimiter = ';', low_memory=False)
```

Is it possible to write some timestamp recognition function?

```
from datetime import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import fnmatch
def get_local_file(date, hour, path='data/'):
        """Get date+hour processing file from local drive

       :param date: str Processing date
        :param hour: str Processing hour
        :param path: str Path to file location
        :return: Pandas DF Retrieved DataFrame
        """
hour = [time(i).strftime(%H) for i in range(24)]
sdate = date.replace('-', '_') + "-" + str(hour)
for p_file in os.listdir(path):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(p_file, 'testingfile-PM*'+sdate+'*.csv'):
            return pd.read_csv(path+p_file, delimiter=';')
```

I found something like this, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to extract date from the name of your csv file, then have a look at the pythons' `datetime` module (or [strptime](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm) method, to be accurate). It allows you to parse the strings into datetimes like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

name = "data/testingfile-PM_18707-2017_06_14-05_03_23__382.csv"

datepart = name.strip("data/testingfile-PM_18707-").split("__")[0] #quick and dirty parsing method that satisfies the given two examples. 

date = datetime.strptime(datepart,"%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
print(datepart)
print(date)
2017_06_14-05_03_23
2017-06-14 05:03:23
```

So if you want to selectively open only 1 day old csvs, you could do something like this:

```
import glob
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

for csv in glob.glob("data/*.csv"):
    datepart = csv.strip("data/testingfile-PM_18707-").split("__")[0]
    date = datetime.strptime(datepart, "%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
    if (now - date).total_seconds() < 3600*24:
        pd.read_csv(csv)
    else:
        print("Too old to care!")
```

Note that this has nothing to do with Pandas itself.

Comment: Did it go well? Male sure you accept the answer if it satisfied your needs.